# UIAlertController Not Within The Window Hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

First of all **please do not mark duplicate on this question** Ive done my research on this topic, and not only have the most recent answers been from over a year ago, but they have also been in C#. Mine also differs from those because I am trying to present my `UIView` from what I assume to be a child of a child view. But I'm not 100% sure about this. So, here is what my code dump looks like after the suggestions.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmPassTxt: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func nextScreen(sender: UIButton) {


    if(emailTxt.text == "" || passwordTxt.text == "" || confirmPassTxt.text == "" || usernameTxt.text == ""){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Wait!", message: "You didn't fill out the required fields, please do so and try again. ", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIKit.UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        if(validateEmail(emailTxt.text!)){
            emailCheck(emailTxt.text!){isValid in if isValid{self.secondRound({ (goodMail, goodPassL, goodPassTxt, nameGood) in
                if (goodMail && goodPassL && goodPassTxt && !nameGood){
                    print("good")
                }else{
                   self.showAlert("Else", description: "Got it?")                    }

                })}else{let alertController=UIAlertController(title: "Whoops!", message: "That email address has already been taken, please try another one", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let defaultAction = UIKit.UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                alertController.parentViewController
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}}
              }else{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Whoops!", message: "That doesnt appear to be a valid email address, please check your information and try again!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let defaultAction = UIKit.UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            alertController.parentViewController
            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }

    }





}
func showAlert(title: String, description: String){
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: description, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let defaultAction = UIKit.UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let DestinationVC : Login2VC = segue.destinationViewController as! Login2VC
    DestinationVC.prepareEmail = emailTxt.text!
    DestinationVC.preparePass = passwordTxt.text!

}

func validateEmail(canidate: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluateWithObject(canidate)
}
func nameFilter(input : String)-> Bool{
    var profanity : Bool = true
    let dataRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    dataRef.child("Profanity").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if(snap.exists()){
            if(snap.value! as! NSArray).containsObject(input){
                print("our ears!")
                profanity = true
            }else{
            profanity = false
        }


    }


}
    return profanity
}
func emailCheck(input: String, callback: (isValid: Bool) -> Void) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(input, password: " ") { (user, error) in
        var canRegister = false

        if error != nil {
            if (error?.code == 17009) {
                canRegister = false
            } else if(error?.code == 17011) {
                //email doesn't exist
                canRegister = true
            }
        }

        callback(isValid: canRegister)
    }
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
func secondRound(callback:(goodMail:Bool, goodPassL:Bool, goodPassTxt:Bool, nameGood:Bool)->Void){
    let availableEmail : Bool = true
    var passwordMatch : Bool = false
    var passwordLength : Bool = false
    var profanity : Bool = false
    if(passwordTxt.text!==confirmPassTxt.text!){passwordMatch=true}else{passwordMatch=false}
    if(passwordTxt.text!.characters.count>=6&&confirmPassTxt.text!.characters.count>=6){passwordLength=true}else{passwordLength=false}
    if(nameFilter(usernameTxt.text!)){profanity=true}else{profanity=false}
    callback(goodMail: availableEmail, goodPassL: passwordLength, goodPassTxt: passwordMatch, nameGood: profanity)


}
}
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is:

1. Check to see if the inputted text is formatted as an email correctly
2. Check to see if the name is available
3. Check if the username contains profanity (pulled as a `json` from firebase)
4. Check to see if the passwords match
5. Check too see if the passwords are at least 6 characters in length

Each `false` result would have its own `UIAlertView` that results from it, but whenever I try to add these views they do not show up, and the app returns with this error. 
**Note, the false event does intact appear in the first condition only. Other than that, nothing happens.**

This is the error I have been getting, and while it seems pretty straight forward I cannot figure out hoe to fix it, nor find any recent information online on how to accomplish this task.

```
> Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fb513fb8bc0> on
> <myApp.LoginViewController: 0x7fb513c6e0a0> whose view is not in the
> window hierarchy!
```

The logical answer to this would be:

> Hey, why don't you just add the window to the hierarchy and be done?

Well, to that question I have a question, if the window is not apart of the hierarchy, then why is the view itself even displaying. Furthermore, why would the first set of `UIAlerts` be displaying, but as soon as I get into a nested `if` they cease? Any ideas on how to fix this terrible error?
Thanks all

Comment: The error message is telling you what is wrong.  The `LoginViewController` is not in the view hierarchy.  You need to first push it onto some other visible view controller or present it.  Start with the `window` object in your app delegate and call `setRootViewController:` on it, then make sure your other view controllers are pushed all the way down to your alert view.

Comment: As @par mentioned there is no problem with UIAlertController, problem exists within your conditions, which possibly could not executed to present alert. Although, again, you should recheck your window hierarchy. I tested your code with custom project, and it runs perfectly.

Comment: @Ethan, what I really recommend you - clean up your code a little, making one simple function for alert, than, obviously, move your network job to background thread, and depending on result present alert on main thread. If you could provide more info, I think, I could be much helpful

Comment: @Ethan, if it is displayed, than obviously it is in window view hierarchy. Try to search problem within another location

Comment: @IgorKislyuk file hosted here, we can move this discussion into chat https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ldat0wvr984hd0/LoginViewController.pages?dl=0

Comment: @IgorKislyuk you've tested it on your own emulator? Because I know for sure that there are valid values being returned from firebase, and even if they weren't then the booleans would push the result into the `else` column, which would still show the display. Yet I see nothing on an emulator or on a phone

Comment: @IgorKislyuk thank you for cleaning that up, but there are some things I have questions about. Because there are so many different conditions, having one callback, `true` or `false` would make it difficult to display the specific error. Could I return a string, and then based on that display the `UIAlertView`?

Comment: @Ethan, Of course you can specify the return result as a string or even the enumeration. Hope I help you. If there are are questions left - just ask them ;)

Comment: @IgorKislyuk still can't get this display to show. We have to be missing some crucial line to actually add the view to the view controller. Also please delete your earlier comments that aren't strictly relevant to this issue, I just don't want to clog up the feed for others is all

Comment: @Ethan, you can again send me this file. I'll watch it later. Truly said, I did not face with presentation problem. This method works perfectly. May be problem happens when you present your controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118880/discussion-between-ethan-and-igor-kislyuk).